# Como usar o servlet context listener para iniciar um servlet assim qua a aplicação for carregada?

Tags: servlet, java

Tenho o seguinte servlet declarado no web.xml e gostaria que ele fosse inicializado antes de qualquer um dos outros servlets da aplicação:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListarFilmesIndex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.corporacao.servlets.ListarFilmesIndex</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListarFilmesIndex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ListarFilmesIndex</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        br.com.corporacao.servlets.InicializacaoServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Tentei implementar a classe que usa `ServletContextListener`:

```java
package br.com.corporacao.servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class InicializacaoServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {

    } 
}
```

Mas não consigo instanciar dentro do método `contextInitialized` o servlet `ListarFilmesIndex` que usa um DAO para carregar todos os filmes que estão cadastrados no banco de dados.

Quando tento instanciar a classe `ListarFilmesIndex` não sei o que fazer com o *request* e o *response* que são necessários para o servlet, e então quando executo a aplicação é lançada uma `NullPointerException`.

Já tentei de tudo e pesquisei mas não encontrei nada, apenas exemplos de filtros e de classes que não são servlets.

O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 3):

Acho que você está bem próximo da solução, mas indo pelo caminho errado.

Primeiro, você fez certo em usar a tag `<load-on-startup>`. Isto faz com que o Servlet seja inicializado durante a inicialização da aplicação.

Porém, um *context listener* não serve para instanciar servlets. Ele apenas permite executar alguma ação exatamente depois da aplicação iniciar e antes de atender a qualquer requisição.

De qualquer forma, para inicializar valores em servlets, não é necessário um *listener*. Basta sobrescrever método [`init`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig)) no seu servlet. [Exemplo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html):

```
public class CatalogServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private BookDBAO bookDB;
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        bookDB = (BookDBAO)getServletContext().
            getAttribute("bookDB");
        if (bookDB == null) throw new
            UnavailableException("Couldn’t get database.");
    }
}
```

Outro detalhe, é que você **não** precisa garantir que esse servlet seja inicializado antes dos outros. Isso porque nenhum servlet vai executar antes da inicialização completa da aplicação, que inclui inicializar e chamar o método `init` de todos os servlets com a tag `<load-on-startup>`.

Entretanto, se realmente a ordem importa, basta deixar os outros servlets sem a tag de inicialização ou colocar valores maiores que `1`.